# Parsing Mix data type matrix log file

Tags: python, file, parsing, matrix

I am trying to parse a complex log file and mixed datatypes (example file. input_file.log)
and extract the min and max value on each category. Data segments are differentiate with id number

Input Log file: **input_file.log**

```
Type:
 id: 12
range_max: 20.0
data1_mix: [inf, 29.7, 0.003, 0.0062, 0.00112]
data2_num: [129.7899, 0.01, 0.0003, 12.0]
Type:
 id: 131
data1: 20.0
data1_mix: [inf, foo, inf, 9.7, 0.0001, 0.02, 0.01]
data2_num: [149.7899, 0.01, 0.03, 12.0]
```

Output Log file: **output_file.log**

```
Order: ID, min value data-1, max value data-2, min value data-1, max value data-2
output_file.log
12, 0.003, 29.7, 0.0003, 129.7899
13, 0.0001, 9.7, 0.01, 149.7899
```

Could you please suggest me how to solve the issue?
Thank you!

Comment: The two `data1_mix` lines don't have the same structure. Is that a typo? If not, what parts are relevant?

Comment: @JackFleeting, it is not a typo. In data1_mix and data2_mix, the relevant parts are only finding the min and max value from each row and discard other info as shown in the output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is somewhat convoluted, but getS the job done, I think:

```
input_file = """[the content of your input_file.log]"""
def is_number(s):
    try:        
        complex(s)        
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True    

print(('ID, min value data-1, max value data-1, min value data-2, max value data-2'))
chunks = input_file.split('Type:\n')
for chunk in chunks[1:]:           
    lines = chunk.strip().splitlines()
    
    line2 = lines[2].split('data1_mix: [')[1].replace('inf','xxx').replace(']','')
    line2 = [float(d) for d in line2.split(',') if is_number(d)!= False]
    line3=lines[3].split('data2_num: [')[1].replace(']','')
    line3 = [float(d) for d in line3.split(',')]       
    
    s_row = ''
    s_row = lines[0].split('id: ')[1]+',\t '+ str(min(line2))+',\t '+str(max(line2))\
    +',\t '+str(min(line3))+',\t '+str(max(line3))
    print(s_row)
```

Output;

```
ID, min value data-1, max value data-1, min value data-2, max value data-2
12,  0.00112,    29.7,   0.0003,     129.7899
131,     0.0001,     9.7,    0.01,   149.7899
```

Comment: is not possible to read out the log file instead of putting the content?